# Use awk to split a file into pieces

Tags: batch-file, printing, awk, split

I am trying to split a file into pieces based on a pattern. The following code:

```
awk "/<MY PATTERN>/{++i;}{print }" %FILE% > Temp.txt
```

Gives me an output like:

```
1
1
1
1
1
1
2
2
2
2
3
3
4
4
4
4
5
5
5
```

I want to print all lines indicated in the output with "1" -- the problem is that the output is only printing the "1" instead of the lines of data.

I know that I am just missing something in the print portion of the code to say something like "Print the lines that are generating a "1" in the output".

I am using windows batch script.

Comment: Please add sample output. Your explanation is very confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

either your example output or your command has problem.....

- why did you need the `i`? it is not used at all.  would the print be `print i`?
- the `/patter/` check makes no sense either. if pattern matched, do `++i`, then print the whole line anyway?
- the question title is about "split file into pieces", I don't see that happened in your codes.

if you got the output like what you shown us (with your current cmd), the output is exactly same as your input.

if the `print` line was `print i`, you could try:

```
awk '/pattern/{++i} i==1{print}' file >newfile
```

again, it is not "splitting", it is extracting. it extracts all lines between the first(inclusive) and second (exclusive) matching lines.

Comment: I apologize for the somewhat inaccurate terminology -- I am still pretty new to batch script coding. I knew that I was very close, but your solution above worked perfectly. I am basically looping through the source file, extracting pieces of it and looping through the pieces to gather data elements. I am sure this seemed elementary but you saved my sanity with this one. VERY much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Change `print` with `if (i==1) print $0`